# How do I cut/paste Mathematica output into a question?

Tags: discussion, formatting

Of all things, I can't find any instructions in the editing-help about how to post my Mathematica output!

Indenting code with four spaces works fine:

```
f = a[x] + c1*b[x] + c2*c[x];
g = Expand[f*f];
h = Distribute[Integrate[g, x]];
Solve[{D[h, c1] == 0, D[h, c2] == 0}, {c1, c2}]
```

But the output posts like this:

{{c1 -> -((([Integral]a[x] c[x] [DifferentialD]x) [Integral]b[x] c[
          x] [DifferentialD]x - ([Integral]a[x] b[
           x] [DifferentialD]x) [Integral]c[
         x]^2 [DifferentialD]x)/(([Integral]b[x] c[
          x] [DifferentialD]x)^2 - ([Integral]b[
          x]^2 [DifferentialD]x) [Integral]c[
         x]^2 [DifferentialD]x)), 
  c2 -> -((([Integral]b[x]^2 [DifferentialD]x) [Integral]a[x] c[
          x] [DifferentialD]x - ([Integral]a[x] b[
           x] [DifferentialD]x) [Integral]b[x] c[
          x] [DifferentialD]x)/(-([Integral]b[x] c[
           x] [DifferentialD]x)^2 + ([Integral]b[
          x]^2 [DifferentialD]x) [Integral]c[
         x]^2 [DifferentialD]x))}}

---

> This is an ouput
>
> ```
> This is an other ouput with some code
> ```

Comment: You could add > before your output so it pops up in a yellow box... that would differentiate it from code.

Comment: @Oska, the link you posted does not have the answer to my question.  Please do not post sarcastic, useless answers.

Comment: @Oska, please read the question I posted before responding again.  As I said, I know how to paste code on mathematica.SE, just indent four spaces.  But I can't find any instructions on how to post my OUTPUT.  Look at the example output I Pasted above; it's not nicely formatted like the output I Copied, with superscript exponents and derivatives and all.  It's unready able.  How do I post on Mathematica.SE example output that looks like the output that Mathematica actually returned to me?

Comment: And putting (* and *) on either side didn't change the formatting.

Comment: @Oska  No, this does not answer my question at all.  Putting a > before the output (as in your example edit) just puts the same hard-to-read text (like I posted in my question) in a pink box; I am asking how to make it format into easy-to-read equations like what I highlighted and copied from my Mathematica window.  Do you understand that?  I am trying to paste my output to SE so that it looks the same as the formatted output I copied from.  If you won't answer my question, could you at least leave my question up so someone else can answer it?

Comment: @Oska  I posted my question elsewhere and someone finally told me all I need to do was put the expression in TexForm and paste it between pairs of $$.  Why didn't you just tell me that instead of giving me an hour-long run-around?

Comment: @JerryGuern Please **don't** do that. There are accepted norms here and posting output as TeXForm just for the heck of it is not generally followed. Sometimes, it is necessary when the question itself is about TeXForm/TraditionalForm, but not otherwise. Please use one of the two formats in the linked question.

Comment: @rm-f  Okay.  See the unreadable example output I posted above in my question?  Can you show me some way to post that so it meets with community practice and is readable?

Comment: The accepted norm is to not use fancy typesetting in code when posting here. The Mathematica frontend is a 2D typesetting system which has its own language, representation, etc. and it is impossible to capture all the vagaries of such a system in HTML using just ASCII/Unicode. I understand that you did not actually typeset this and this is in fact what `Solve` returns. However, ask yourself this — Is the complicated output _really_ necessary for the question, especially since most folks here have Mathematica? More often than not, just a well formatted input with error messages is sufficient.

Comment: @rm-f Okay, I see what you're saying.  But my question should not have been merged into this other question.  I was asking how to post TeXForm, not about SE preferred formatting.  The fellow who merged the question did not seem to understand what I was asking, even after some discussion.

Comment: You may prefer posting the `InputForm` of the expression, but of course it's not as nice as what you wanted. Also note that there is an integral symbol in unicode that gets correctly interpreted by MMA, but as there is no standard unicode symbol corresponding to `\[DifferentialD]` we cannot make a nice unicode string that gets interpreted the right way by MMA. About the closing, if you want the question to be reopened, try editing the question to make it clear what you were after, so that one does not have to read the comments for this.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom  Okay, thank you.  Speaking as a SE noob, this site really needs  an easy source of this info for noobs. Look what I had to go through to get answers to this rather obvious question. The Ask input window has formatting tabs for lots of stuff but not an obvious thing like "MMA Output". And I' ll point out that noobs are far more likely to Search on the question I asked as I phrased it than on the aesthetics question mine was merged into. Who where can I send this suggestion to? I'd be happy to write it up myself if I thought I had the complete answer, but I doubt I do.

Comment: JerryGuern, I agree that an overview of such information would be nice. Note that the help buttons and pages give only generic information about formatting on the SO/SE-network and nothing specific for this site. The information provided is in fact exactly the same as on stackoverflow. I doubt we have control over what the help buttons show. So it may not be an option to create a tab labeled "mma output" or something like that. To verify that this is indeed impossible you/I would have to ask halirutan or @rm-rf.

Comment: Also note that closed duplicate questions are kept and regarded as valuable, mostly because they point to other Q&As but can be found using different searches. Closing the question does not mean we don't want people to find it.

Comment: @rm-rf Bringing discussion back to you at Jacob's suggestion. Plz read his comments above. I'll add: 1) Everyone benefits if MMA-SE noobs can easily find this info that I had to spend days prying from various people. A succinct authoritative answer to my Q would be useful page to direct noobs to. 2) My Q is NOT a duplicate of the one it was merged into. 3) I hope it comes across, I have the info I need now, I'm trying to be helpful now. I'd write an Answer page up myself if I had complete info.

Comment: @JerryGuern My hands are tied — this is a site that's running on the SE software that is common to all sites and we don't have the ability to edit in site specific instructions into the dialog boxes. I think the question that you are asking is addressed in [this question](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2/5). Please feel free to add an answer there if you feel an alternate proposal for `TeXForm` output is better than the ones already in use.

Comment: @rm-r No, that question is about code not MMA output. And if we can't change the info tabs on the input window, we could at least put the info in an Answer to my question so that noobs can find it. The very fact of how much trouble I've had to go to find this simple information proves how badly such an Answer page is needed.